# Switch on/off text color between two elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm very new to jquery. In essence, when I click "a", I'd like to make "a" stay a different color and size until "b" is clicked. When "b" is clicked, I'd like to make "b" stay a different color and size until "a" is again clicked. Almost like a toggle effect, but alternating between two elements - it's rather simple, I just can't figure it out. Thanks in advance for the help.

```js
$("#letter-a, #letter-b").click(function() {
  css('color','#f49242'), css('font-size','14px');
});
```

```css
#letter-a, #letter-b {
  float: left;
  color: #03f;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="letter-a">
a
</div>
<div id="letter-b">
b
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the `css()` method on the element that got clicked. To do that, you pass the `this` object to JQuery and call the `css` method on that wrapped set object. So:

```
css('color','#f49242'), css('font-size','14px');
```

Should be:

```
$(this).css('color','#f49242').css('font-size','14px');
```

Or, a more condensed version that the `.css()` method allows you to use when you have more than one css property to alter:

```
$(this).css({'color':'#f49242', 'font-size':'14px'});
```

But, really the better way to this is by setting up two CSS classes ahead of time and just toggling the use of them. Also, rather than using `div` here, `span` is more appropriate.

```js
$(".normal").click(function() {
  $("span").removeClass("special");    // Reset all letters
  $(this).addClass("special");         // Apply special to just element that was clicked
});
```

```css
/* This is applied in the HTML by default */
.normal {
  color: #03f;
  font-size: 12pt;
}

/* This will be applied as needed */
.special {
  color: #f49242;
  font-size: 14pt;
}

.clickable {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="normal clickable">a</span>
<span class="normal clickable">b</span>
```

Comment: battleCry12, This answer fixes the error in your code. A cleaner approach is to have the "active" style in a class so you can easily toggle the styles by changing which element has that class.

Comment: I appreciate this. Now that it's been shown to me, it does make sense just to apply pre-defined classes as opposed to adding css through jquery. Thanks a bunch, I appreciate it, definitely.

Comment: Your "whould be" `42'), $(th` is wrong. Try using `;`